# How do I get a value from one while loop to another?

Tags: python, pygame

Basically I have this pong game. I run the start menu and in the start menu i have an image that is a rectangle that is the selection box for if the user will choose single player or two player. Right now I'm doing a check on the Y coordinate of the rectangle to then define a value called 'gamechoice' and depending on what the value of gamechoice is will determine whether it's single play or two player. The problem is, after defining gamechoice in my main menu while loop it does not carry over the value and says that gamechoice is undefined

I cannot find anything about this on the internet

```
def game_intro():

    intro = True
    rect_x = 340
    rect_y = 130
    gamechoice = 0

    while intro:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
        backgroundimage = pygame.image.load('background.jpg')
        screen.blit(backgroundimage,(0,0))

        #-----------------------------------------------------------------
        #   you ended here trying to make
        #   a selection rectangle you need to make it hollow
        #-----------------------------------------------------------------


        #selection rectangle
        rect = pygame.image.load('rect.png')
        screen.blit(rect,(rect_x,rect_y))


        #Text size for title
        screenText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf',60)

        #text size for selection
        screenText2 = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf',25)

        #Display Title "Pong"
        TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("Pong", screenText)
        TextRect = ((360),(65))
        gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

        #Display selection "Single Player"
        TextSurf2, TextRect2 = text_objects("Single Player", screenText2)
        TextRect2 = ((350),(135))
        gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf2, TextRect2)

        #Display selection "Two Player"
        TextSurf3, TextRect3 = text_objects("Two Player", screenText2)
        TextRect3 = ((370),(175))
        gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf3, TextRect3)

        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_UP:
                    rect_y = 130
                elif event.key == K_DOWN:
                    rect_y = 170

        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_SPACE:
                    intro = False

        if rect_y == 130:
            gamechoice = 1


        if rect_y == 170:
            gamechoice = 2

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(15)
```

It will use the value of gamechoice to determine whether to not its single player or multi player

Comment: "says that gamechoice is undefined" is not a problem description. Please provide the complete error message and a [mcve] where this error occurs.

Comment: Sounds like you should be returning gamechoice to whatever is calling it. I don't think you've included enough to information understand where the error is occurring.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the `game_intro` method in another part of the code it would be a good a idea to return the value of the `gamechoice`:

```
def game_intro():
# ... the first part of your method
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(15)
    return gamechoice


if __name__ == '__main__':
    choice = game_intro()
    if choice == 1: 
          # do stuff
    # ...  rest of the program
```